# Is continueability [continuability] a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

It appears that "Continueability" does not get a lot of hits on Google, which usually is a good indication to avoid it. What would be a good repalcement? "Ability to continue" doesn't do it for me.

Comment: Could you add a sentence showing how you want to use the word? It may influence what is suggested.

Comment: Given the spelling of *continuation*, I would suggest that you have an extra 'e' in *continuability*.

Comment: If you want an alternative, please can you give a sample sentence that shows us the context. You could invent a sentence and leave a blank where the word would fit.  Without context there are too many possibilities.

Comment: If something *has* to continue rather than *can* continue, then you could consider unstoppability. It is [marginally more common than continuability](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=continuability%2Cunstoppability&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontinuability%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunstoppability%3B%2Cc0). But we really need an example sentence for context, as @chasly says. Even then, I suspect the most helpful answer is going to be "reword your sentence to avoid the need for this word".

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily conclude from a paucity of Google hits that a word is inappropriate (although it does seem to point out your misspelling).  Conversely one ought not be too quick  to judge a word/usage to be appropriate for your purposes based _simply on a high number of ghits_ — misusage can be propagated quickly when people take this "blind leading the blind" approach.

Comment: Presumably they have in mind something like: *The recent earthquake in Twickenham places in doubt the continuability of the Rugby World Cup* (God forbid)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is used in a few contexts, but notice the spelling.

[On **Continuability** of Solutions of Second Order Differential Equations](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2038127?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

The [Google ngram:continuability,continuation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=continuability%2Ccontinuation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontinuability%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinuation%3B%2Cc0) gives an indication of how rare the word is in published works. Click on the links at the bottom of the ngram page to see the actual texts.

If you wish for alternatives, please give us a sample sentence for context. Thanks.

Comment: I find this spelling to be compelling enough not to use any alternative. Thanks.